# struggling with special characters (html_entity_decode, iconv, and more)

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I've been struggling with getting a bunch of characters translated down to core utf-8 to store them in my database.

PHP iconv fails on many characters, so i've been forced to build my own 'solution', which really isn't a solution if it doesn't work, and it fails almost completely in windows, so developing with iconv is mostly fruitless as I have to 'dev' on the test server. Also, as iconv misses a ton of characters, it isn't very helpful at all.

Here's what i've got my function doing

```
function replace_accents($string) { 
  return str_replace( array('à','á','â','ã','ä', 'ç', 'è','é','ê','ë', 'ì','í','î','ï', 'ñ', 'ò','ó','ô','õ','ö', 'ù','ú','û','ü', 'ý','ÿ', 'À','Á','Â','Ã','Ä', 'Ç', 'È','É','Ê','Ë', 'Ì','Í','Î','Ï', 'Ñ', 'Ò','Ó','Ô','Õ','Ö', 'Ù','Ú','Û','Ü', 'Ý'), array('a','a','a','a','a', 'c', 'e','e','e','e', 'i','i','i','i', 'n', 'o','o','o','o','o', 'u','u','u','u', 'y','y', 'A','A','A','A','A', 'C', 'E','E','E','E', 'I','I','I','I', 'N', 'O','O','O','O','O', 'U','U','U','U', 'Y'), $string); 
} 


function replaceQuote($string){
$replaceQuote=array('‘', '’', '“', '”', ''','‚','„',''',"’");
    return str_replace($replaceQuote,'\'', $string);
}

function replaceArray($string){
$replaceArray=array('—', '™','™','™','©', '®', '®','©',
                    '¡',
                    '¡',
                    '¢',
                    '¢',
                    '£',
                    '£',
                    '¤',
                    '¥',
                    '¥',
                '¦',
            '§',
                '§',
            '«',
            '«',
            '¬',
            '¬',
            '­',
            '¯',
            '¯',
        '²',
            '³',
            'µ',
            'µ',
            '¶',
            '¶',
            '·',
            '·',
            '¸',
            '¸',
            '¹',
        'º',
        'º','»',  '‹', '»','¼', '½','¾','♥', '☆', '☠', '░','▒','▓','█', '★',
'♪','♫','◄','▀','▄','►', '¤', '^', '☣', '…', '†', '‡', '.:','♣','Ξ','ξ','↠','⇒','→','↞','⇐','←',
'⇔','↔','™','♠','&loz','√','∩','&Cap','∴');
  return str_replace($replaceArray, '', $string);
  }

function special_replace($string){
   $replace_from=array('ƒ', 'Œ','œ','•', '–', '—','˜','š','Š','Ÿ','ÿ','ε',
   '€','α','Α','τ','Τ','θ','Θ');

   $replace_to=array('ƒ', 'Œ','œ','•','-','-','~','š','Š','Ÿ','ÿ','ε','€','α','Α','τ','Τ','θ','Θ');
 return str_replace($replace_from, $replace_to, $string);


}

function dbSlug($slugIt){
$slugIt=html_entity_decode($slugIt);

$slugIt=replaceArray($slugIt);
$slugIt=replaceQuote($slugIt);
$slugIt=special_replace($slugIt);

//$slugIt=iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $slugIt);
$slugIt=replace_accents($slugIt);
$slugIt=trim($slugIt);
        return $slugIt;

    }
```

It may seem inefficient to as I have the same character in multiple replace functions sometimes but I use the functions in multiple places in different ways, so this is why I may have the same character in more than one of my replace functions.

Now, the problem is that every time I go and look at the data, I find ANOTHER special character that isn't caught through my labyrinth of finding and replacing/removing characters.

The currently offensive character is what you'd think would be a rather harmless ' '.
Which are ending up in the database as 'Â'. Not all spaces mind you, it appears only to affect some spaces (i haven't figured out why yet).

I've been at this for more than a week, and every time I go back and look, i've got more to add to the 'fix'.

I'm not asking how to remove 'Â', I am hoping to get a resolution as to how to maintain the integrity of the content/data but not have special characters which get really messed-up sometimes when moving data around, and maintaining searchability.

I would do

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9,-\'-!&.etc]/", "", $data);
```

, but am concerned that i would start screwing up words where special characters which got missed get replaced. 
I already had this experience where 'México' was coming out 'Mxico', so that just doesn't work.

The character encoding is supposed to be UTF-8, though I've tried changing the header to ISO-8859-1 before encoding, or not setting any encoding, and I always get the same result.

I'm sure what I've got is probably the worst possible way of doing this, but I haven't been able to find an effective solution. Any suggestions? My concern is that this is almost never ending and I'm always finding new characters that are being missed through my labyrinth of translation.

Comment: Is your actual problem you're trying to solve about storing utf8 encoded characters in mysql? All that transliteration code seems to to indicate that you have a problem with your mysql connection charset and you can't actually send utf8 characters.

Comment: Not all the code is about storing utf8 encoded characters, some of it is actually about stripping out useless characters like '★'. It seems the problem may be two fold. eyze's answer seemed (I hope) to clean up what was left from the stuff I had already stripped out/replaced. Unfortunately, my server doesn't seem to be accepting the encoding in the file, so the stripped (or attempted) characters are still not being removed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Save your PHP files as UTF-8.
2. Upon connection do SET NAMES 'UTF8';

If you still need to replace characters do the following:

```
$string = preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
```

**EDIT**:

```
$string = html_entity_decode(preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: WOW!! that's nice and concise. And it works really well too (on the limited test I've done). 
One question though,the htmlentites in preg_replace. I'm trying to get non-html encoded characters. I'm noticing some spaces coming out as &nbsp, and I have some quotes still coming through as &quot, and &rsquo, etc. That is just in the very limited testing I've done so far, and I removed all the stuff I had done originally. I've copied the preg_replace exactly as you've provided it.

Comment: From my intial test on your edit, i am noticing an issue with quotes. I've changed it to htmlentities($string, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'). That seems ok, but I'm getting 'â€™' for '’'. I would have expected that to come out as RSQUO at the least, but unfortunately not. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use , html_entity_decode($strint,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')

I had problems with spanish special chars. With this I solved it